# Why does import work with <iostream> but not work with <string> or other libraries?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to learn how to work with C++20. I changed the compiler version. I tried almost everything. But there is a problem.

The `import` statement works "when it wants so". The `#include` statement works fine.

If I import `<iostream>`:

```
import <iostream>; // ok 
import <chrono>; // ok too (the only two libraries that work)
```

It'll work, but sometimes it won't. But if I import, for example, `<string>`:

```
import <string>; // error  C7612: could not find header unit for 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\string'
```

The most strange thing is that sometimes all std's statements can make a lot of errors. But my question is:

Why does `import <iostream>` work but `import <string>` doesn't?

I tried to change the order of importing.

Comment: C++20 is the language version, not the compiler version. Your compiler is apparently Visual C++. What version is your compiler?

Comment: I use visual studio IDE so Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) 19.34.31937

Comment: The fact that it works with the 20th standard. So it works with modules, export, import etc

Comment: @m1ss1k -- Did you set your project to use C++20?  By defaut, I believe the standard is set to C++14.

Comment: Yep, I set my project in the properties to use C++20.

Comment: I *think* you need to follow the preparation walkthrough on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-import-stl-header-units?view=msvc-170) to set up the header units.

Comment: Modules support in MSVC 2019 is incomplete / buggy. I suggest you to upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 17.5 Preview version. That one has a preliminary support for `import std;` that will become standard in C++23. I think we should use `import std;` for new code with modules, and forget about things like `import <header>;` that I guess will never be completely implemented.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, your solution helped me to solve the problem

Comment: @prapin: `import<…>;` is standard **too**, and hopefully its support will continue to improve for libraries not yet made into named modules, but yes you should used the latter (including `std`) if possible.